# Tricky Simple Python

Tags: python, if-statement

Can any one please explain me why the if condition is working.

```
x = 0xA5

if x == 0xAA or 0x5A or 0xA0 or 0xAB:
    print "Host Address is Correct"



0xAA or 0x5A or 0xA0 or 0xAB binary operation is not equal to 0xA5 either
```

Comment: `0x5A` is true, so the condition is true. Perhaps you meant `x in (0xAA, 0x5A, 0xA0, 0xAB)`?

Comment: Perhaps you want to check whether x equals to any of those values?

Comment: `if x in [0xAA, 0x5A, 0xA0, 0xAB]`

Comment: 0x5A is 90 - what do you mean it is true?

Comment: @JeshKundem> any non-zero integer is considered true when evaluated as a boolean (such as here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python isn't doing what you think it is  - when you say

```
if x == 0xAA or 0x5A or 0xA0 or 0xAB:
```

it's checking if `x==0xAA` **or** `0x5a` is "truthy" - wherein a non-empty string, for example, is considered `True` - and so on. The error you are getting suggests one of `0x5A, 0xA0, 0xAB` is "truthy". What you would need to do is

```
if x == 0xAA or x == 0x5A or x == 0xA0 or x == 0xAB:
```

Which can be expressed more easily as

```
if x in [0xAA, 0x5A, 0xA0, 0xAB]:
```

Though it should be noted that if `0xAA` etc are strings, they need to be written as `'0xAA'` etc.

Comment: It is not checking if `0x5a == True`, which is obviously false, it checks if it is truthy.

Comment: You're right, @FranciscoCouzo, bad wording form me. I'll edit to rephrase

Answer (score 2):

Its because of operator precedence, `==` has higer precedence then `or` so 
`x==0xAA` evaluated first and return `False` but each of other hex characters returns True, so basically your expression becomes 
`x = False or True or True or True` which will result in True.

You should modify your code to get the op you want.

```
x = 0xA5

if x == (0xAA or 0x5A or 0xA0 or 0xAB):
    print("Host Address is Correct")
```

Check operator precedence here
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/operators_precedence_example.htm

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants (computing 0xAA or 0xA0 makes no sense). I think he actually wanted to compare to each value.

Comment: @Spectras well his question was why it was not working, he wasnt clear on what he wants

Answer (score 0):

saurabh is right about it being a precedence problem, you expression is being evaluated like this:

```
x == (0xAA or 0x5A or 0xA0 or 0xAB)
```

When you most probably want to use:

```
x in (0xAA, 0x5A, 0xA0, 0xAB)
```